# How to separate curves with roots near the mesh surface in geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

How to separate roots near the surface of the grid in geometric nodes?
I have extracted edges as curves from the existing mesh head, but the root positions are confused and there are many of them. It takes a lot of time to do it manually.
Therefore, I thought of using geometric nodes to select the roots near the surface of the grid, and then do a flip. This will increase efficiency a lot.
However, I am not familiar with geometric nodes, and I would like to ask for help from professional giants.

[image]

"Curve Root"：
[image]

[image]

Comment: "Curve Root" is a custom group. We don't know what it is, and therefore we can't help.

Comment: Curve Root "is the official hair node group for blender3.5 or later versions

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm not into hair.

Comment: It's okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to [Blunder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/107598/blunder) for answering my question in another question, which helped me find a solution to this problem.

My solution is as follows:

[image]